# How to append line with strings at the end of variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, perl

We have the following line in file

```
more file


USA_FORMAT="-XX:LOP83746=5M -XX:+YU3635-2837"
```

and we want to append the following strings (line) also at the end of **USA_FORMAT** variable

```
/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/man/man1/jarsigner.1 /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/examples/jars 6 3 END
```

How to append the line `"usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/man/man1/jarsigner.1 /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/examples/jars 6 3 END"` in the variable by sed or Perl one line / other approach?

NOTE -  content of variable before appending can be different.

Expected output:

```
USA_FORMAT="-XX:LOP83746=5M -XX:+YU3635-2837 usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/man/man1/jarsigner.1 /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/examples/jars 6 3 END"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^USA_FORMAT=/s,"$, /usr/.../jarsigner.1 /usr/.../jars 6 3 END",'
```

i.e. on the line that starts with `USA_FORMAT=`, replace the final `"` with `/usr/...END"` (with the final quote at the end of the new string). If it's a shell script, you could actually ignore the existing quote and instead add the new part with a new set of quotes. You'd get `var="foo""bar"`, but that's completely valid.

Or similarly in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's,"$, /usr/.../jarsigner.1 /usr/.../jars 6 3 END", if /^USA_FORMAT=/'
```

or

```
export repl='/usr/ ... END'
perl -pe 's/"$/ $ENV{repl}"/ if /^USA_FORMAT=/'
```

so you don't need to choose the separator for `s` based on what the replacement string (doesn't) contain(s).

Answer (score 0):

let the data in 'd', on bash shell terminal do;

```
append='/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/man/man1/jarsigner.1 /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/examples/jars 6 3 END'
sed -E "/USA_FORMAT=.+/ s~~&$append~" d
```